# Matplotlib - Return dataset after zoom/pan

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create a pair of scatter plots on the same figure

If scatter plot 1 is zoomed or panned I want to redisplay scatter plot 2 such that only the new data set is displayed

The sub plots share the same underlying dataset but don't share equivalent axes so I can;t use sharex, sharey etc., .e.g. scatterplot 2 is the result of applying a different function to the same data shown in scatterplot 1 that results in different axes

I think I need to somehow extract the data set displayed each tme scatter plot 1 is zoomed/panned and pass that data to the function that plots scatter plot 2 but I cannot find any info on how this could be done

must be very common - i'm surprised I haven't unearthed any cook-book type scripts for it

i have had some luck with returning sets of scatter point indices using the 'picker' event - what i really need is something that returns the scatter point indices for all visible points triggered after a zoom/pan event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the axes view intervals:

```
xinterval, yinterval = ax.xaxis.get_view_interval(), ax.yaxis.get_view_interval()
```

Then use the intervals to determine which points are visible in the first subplot and use that to decide what/how to show the second subplot.  For example:

```
plt.scatter(xs, ys)

xmin, xmax = ax.xaxis.get_view_interval()
ymin, ymax = ax.yaxis.get_view_interval()
indices = np.where((xmin <= xs) & (xs <= xmax) & (ymin <= ys) & (ys <= ymin))
```

Comment: i'd been going down a similar route looking at event.inaxes.get_xlim() and event.inaxes.get_ylim() on a 'button_release_event' i'm surprised there isn't an easier way though, i.e. an axes method that returns all indices to x and y visible data points for a given scatter plot

Comment: @Hiett I could be wrong, but I am pretty sure that the backends draw _everything_ and then only display the section you asked for, so knowing which points are visible isn't all that important most of the time.

Comment: @tcaswell ok that makes sense - i've just come across xlim_changed and ylim_changed events which i think could be useful

Comment: @Hiett This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672580/creating-matplotlib-lasso-function-embed-it-in-wxpython and the links contained may be relevant.

Comment: @ecatmur i get an error on the indices line - *** ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() have resorted to using np.logical_and() instead

Comment: @Hiett oh yeah, forgot the parentheses.  Try that - note that it's single ampersand, not double.